# What does the different seats do?

Tags: ps-vita, disgaea-3

In the Classroom when I move near a seat some have different names, ie. Nerd's Seat, Secretive Seat, etc.

They don't seem to have an obvious pattern to their placement and when I move characters around the names of the seat don't move with them (so they're fixed).

So I am wondering what the purpose of these names are? Do they give particular bonuses and if so what?

Answer (score 1):

Characters in adjacent seats are more likely to combo with each other when using normal attacks. The names of the seats are irrelevant.